# Setting varying columns for a subset of rows in a pandas multiindex dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, assign

I want to re-assign values in specific rows and varying multi-index columns of a large pandas dataframe, df, to non NaN values that have been calculated and stored in a slightly smaller masked subset of the dataframe, df_sub.

```
df =
    A                                                           B        
      0     1     2     3     4     5     6     7     8     9      0     1     2     3     4     5     6     7     8     9        
0   1.0   2.0   3.0   4.0   5.0   6.0   7.0   8.0   9.0  10.0  -51.0 -50.0 -49.0 -48.0 -47.0 -46.0 -45.0 -44.0 -43.0 -42.0   
1  11.0  12.0  13.0  14.0  15.0  16.0  17.0  18.0  19.0  20.0  -41.0 -40.0 -39.0 -38.0 -37.0 -36.0 -35.0 -34.0 -33.0 -32.0   
2  21.0  22.0  23.0  24.0  25.0  26.0  27.0  28.0  29.0  30.0  -31.0 -30.0 -29.0 -28.0 -27.0 -26.0 -25.0 -24.0 -23.0 -22.0   
3  31.0  32.0  33.0  34.0  35.0  36.0  37.0  38.0  39.0  40.0  -21.0 -20.0 -29.0 -28.0 -27.0 -26.0 -25.0 -24.0 -23.0 -22.0   
4  41.0  42.0  43.0  44.0  45.0  46.0  47.0  48.0  49.0  50.0  -11.0 -10.0  -9.0  -8.0  -7.0  -6.0  -5.0  -4.0  -3.0  -2.0  

df_sub =
      0     1     2     3     4     5     6     7     8     9 
1    NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   0.3   0.2   0.1   NaN   NaN
3    NaN   NaN   NaN   0.6   0.9   0.7   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
```

My goal is to get the result, shown below, for df.loc[:,'B'] where the non NaN values in df_sub replace the respective row and columns of `df (i.e., df.loc[1, pd.IndexSlice['B', 5:7]] = df_sub.loc[1, 5:7] and df.loc[3, pd.IndexSlice['B', 3:5]] = df_sub.loc[3, 3:5])`:

```
df.loc[:,'B'] =
      0     1     2     3     4     5     6     7     8     9
0 -51.0 -50.0 -49.0 -48.0 -47.0 -46.0 -45.0 -44.0 -43.0 -42.0
1 -41.0 -40.0 -39.0 -38.0 -37.0   0.3   0.2   0.1 -33.0 -32.0
2 -31.0 -30.0 -29.0 -28.0 -27.0 -26.0 -25.0 -24.0 -23.0 -22.0
3 -21.0 -20.0 -19.0   0.6   0.9   0.7 -15.0 -14.0 -13.0 -12.0
4 -11.0 -10.0  -9.0  -8.0  -7.0  -6.0  -5.0  -4.0  -3.0  -2.0
```

However, rather getting the desired values, I am getting NaNs:

```
df.loc[:,'B'] =
      0     1     2     3     4     5     6     7     8     9
0 -51.0 -50.0 -49.0 -48.0 -47.0 -46.0 -45.0 -44.0 -43.0 -42.0
1 -41.0 -40.0 -39.0 -38.0 -37.0   NaN   NaN   NaN -33.0 -32.0
2 -31.0 -30.0 -29.0 -28.0 -27.0 -26.0 -25.0 -24.0 -23.0 -22.0
3 -21.0 -20.0 -19.0   NaN   NaN   NaN -15.0 -14.0 -13.0 -12.0
4 -11.0 -10.0  -9.0  -8.0  -7.0  -6.0  -5.0  -4.0  -3.0  -2.0
```

My simple sample code is included below.  From the diagnostics, it looks like everything is behaving as expected: 1) the non-nan values and their indices from df_sub are identified for each row of df_sub, 2) the slicing of the original df appears to be correct, and 3) the assignment is made without a complaint or a "setting copy" warning.

1. What is the appropriate way to accomplish my goal?
2. Why is this failing?
3. Is there a more compact, efficient way to perform the assignments?

Simplified example:

```
# Create data for example case
idf = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['A', 'B'], np.arange(0,10)])
df = pd.DataFrame(np.concatenate((np.arange(1.,51.).reshape(5,10), 
                  np.arange(-51., -1.).reshape(5,10)), axis=1), 
                  index=np.arange(0,5), columns=idf)
df_sub = pd.DataFrame([[np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, np.nan, np.nan], 
                      [np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan]],
                      index=[1,3], columns=np.arange(0,10))
dfsub_idx = df_sub.index

# Perform assignments
for (idx, row) in df_sub.iterrows() :
   arr = row.index[~row.isnull()] 
   print 'row {}: \n{}'.format(idx, row)
   print 'non-nan indices: {}\n'.format(arr)
   print 'df before mod: \n{}'.format(df.loc[idx, pd.IndexSlice['B', arr.tolist()]])
   df.loc[idx, pd.IndexSlice['B', arr.tolist()]] = row[arr] 
   print 'df after mod: \n{}'.format(df.loc[idx, pd.IndexSlice['B', arr.tolist()]])
```

Answer (score 2):

You should add `values` at the end of `df_sub` after `.iloc`

```
df.loc[1, pd.IndexSlice['B', 5:7]] = df_sub.loc[1, 5:7].values 
df.loc[3, pd.IndexSlice['B', 3:5]] = df_sub.loc[3, 3:5].values
```

Comment: Nice answer (-:

Answer (score 2):

### Inline with `pandas.DataFrame.align` and `pandas.DataFrame.fillna`

By using the `level` argument

```
pd.DataFrame.fillna(*df_sub.align(df, level=1))

      A                                                           B                                                      
      0     1     2     3     4     5     6     7     8     9     0     1     2     3     4     5     6     7     8     9
0   1.0   2.0   3.0   4.0   5.0   6.0   7.0   8.0   9.0  10.0 -51.0 -50.0 -49.0 -48.0 -47.0 -46.0 -45.0 -44.0 -43.0 -42.0
1  11.0  12.0  13.0  14.0  15.0   0.5   0.6   0.7  19.0  20.0 -41.0 -40.0 -39.0 -38.0 -37.0   0.5   0.6   0.7 -33.0 -32.0
2  21.0  22.0  23.0  24.0  25.0  26.0  27.0  28.0  29.0  30.0 -31.0 -30.0 -29.0 -28.0 -27.0 -26.0 -25.0 -24.0 -23.0 -22.0
3  31.0  32.0  33.0   0.3   0.4   0.5  37.0  38.0  39.0  40.0 -21.0 -20.0 -19.0   0.3   0.4   0.5 -15.0 -14.0 -13.0 -12.0
4  41.0  42.0  43.0  44.0  45.0  46.0  47.0  48.0  49.0  50.0 -11.0 -10.0  -9.0  -8.0  -7.0  -6.0  -5.0  -4.0  -3.0  -2.0
```

---

### In place with `update`

```
df.update(df_sub.align(df, level=1)[0])
```

---

### Clarification

This:

```
pd.DataFrame.fillna(*df_sub.align(df, level=1))
```

Is equivalent to

```
a, b = df_sub.align(df, level=1)
a.fillna(b)
# Or pd.DataFrame.fillna(a, b)
```

Comment: It's called a splat.  It has to do with unpacking.  What is returned by `align` is a tuple of two values.  By proceeding it with a splat, I've told Python to pass those two elements in the tuple as the first two arguments to the `fillna` function.  I'll edit the post to clarify.

Comment: I accidentally deleted my question before I realized you had answered me, so I'm posting what my question initially was:

   _Genuis! Thank you!  I have an additional question though.  I am trying to understand what is happening with the asterisk (*) preceding the argument in the fillna() function.  I tried searching the web but so far haven't found a good explanation.  Could you please explain or provide a link that might help me?_

Thank you for the clarification.

Comment: Actually, the above solution affects the result of df['A'] **AND** df['B'] where I only wanted to change df['B'].  In my actual situation, I have 7 categories (e.g., df['A'] through df['G')] each having 39 sublevels, so I would rather be able to align df_sub with just df['B'] and then update df['B'].  I'm still haven't been successful in accomplishing this without getting the "SettingWithCopyError".  I've tried update() with the inplace=True as well as doing something like df.loc[:, 'B'] but to no avail.  Further advice would be appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: I also failed to mention that in reality, for my particular case, I have 134550 rows in df, while df_sub is a modified copy of 1051 selected rows of the original df (e.g., df.loc[selected row idx, pdIndexSlice['B', :]]). Thus, duplicating the entire dataframe can be undesirable.

Comment: Never mind....figured it out.  df['B'] = pd.DataFrame.fillna(*df_sub.align(df['B'], level=1)) does the trick. Thanks for your insight....very helpful....and learned something new!